# Tool that works outside the browser window

Tags: javascript, web, cloud

I am curious if there is a way to create a tool in javascript or any other language for a web app that will work outside the browser window as well. For example an eyedropper tool that takes the color from a section on your desktop. In other words the functionality to not be confided within the browser window.

Comment: Do you mean like browser extensions?

Comment: If it works outside the browser, then it's not really a _web_ application, now is it.

Comment: Well not quite .. It s a design app on the cloud.. And like in photoshop you have the tool that takes the color from wherever you want and tells you the code of the color. But what if i wanted to take a color from an element the is not in the browser.. When my cursor leaves the browser window i only have the arrow tool the tool from my app is working only within those borders

Comment: But it would be cool if i could .. And i wanted to see if it s even possible

Comment: Maybe you can use ajax to request and send data to the server without requiring a browser.